# SKlearn is giving me a ValueError: Shapes of X and y do not match exception

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Been having some trouble with SKlearn for a project. My goal is to use SKlearn to determine how many people on the titanic died relative to their class. Here is my screwed up code so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as P
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model.stochastic_gradient import SGDClassifier
from sklearn import linear_model


#The goal of this project is to understand how many people on the Titanic died when    compared to their class.
#reading in the dataframe from train.csv
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=0)
#grabbing Pclass and Survived for data bits. 
train = df['Pclass'].values
target = df['Survived'].values

#converting into a numpy array. 
train = np.array(train)
target = np.array(target)
print target.shape, train.shape

#testing
clf = SGDClassifier(loss='log')
#clf = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, random_state=33)
clf.fit(train, target)
test = [3, 1, 0, 2]
print("Result is: " + str(clf.predict(test)))
prob = clf.predict_proba(test)
print("\nProbabilities: ")
print(prob)
#display coefficients
print("\nCoefficients of the features:\n")
print(clf.coef_)
#display the intercept
print("\nIntercept: ")
print(clf.intercept_)
```

The following is my output:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/Shock's lab/PycharmProjects/Bigdata/project.py"
(891,) (891,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shock's lab/PycharmProjects/Bigdata/project.py", line 24, in <module>
    clf.fit(train, target)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 519, in fit
sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 418, in _fit
classes, sample_weight, coef_init, intercept_init)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 345, in _partial_fit
_check_fit_data(X, y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 229, in _check_fit_data
raise ValueError("Shapes of X and y do not match.")
ValueError: Shapes of X and y do not match.
```

Any help in explaining this exception and getting around it would be greatly appreciated.

edit: here is the output for my train and target:

(891,) (891,)

train is [3 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 3 1 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 3 1 1 3 2 1 1 3
 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 2 1 1 2 3 2 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3
 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 1 2 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1
 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 3 2 3 2 2 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 3 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3
 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 3 1 2 3 3 2 3 2 3
 1 3 1 3 3 2 2 3 2 1 1 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 2 3 2 3 1 3 2 1 2 3 2
 3 3 1 3 2 3 2 3 1 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 3 3 1 3 2 1 2 3 3 1 3 3 3 1 1 1
 2 3 3 1 1 3 2 3 3 1 1 1 3 2 1 3 1 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 2 3 1 1 2 3 3 1
 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 3 2 3 2 2 1 1 3 3 2 2 3 1 3 2 3 1 3 1 1
 3 1 3 1 1 3 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 1 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 1
 1 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 1 3 2 3 2 3 2 1 3 3 1 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3
 2 3 3 3 3 1 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 1 3 2 3 1 1 3 2 1 2 2 3 3 2
 3 1 2 1 3 1 2 3 1 1 3 3 1 1 2 3 1 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 1 2 3 3 3 3
 2 3 3 1 3 1 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 3 3 1 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 3 1 2 3
 2 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 1 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 1 1 3 1 1 3 3 2 1 1 2 2 3 2 1 2 3 3 3
 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 1 3 3 3 2 1 3 3 2 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 3 3 3 1
 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 1 2 3 1 3 1 3 3 1 2 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 1 3 3 3 1 2 1 3
 3 1 3 1 1 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 1 1 3 1 3 3 2
 2 3 3 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 3 1 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 3 3 3 1 2 3 3 1 3 1 1 3
 3 3 2 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 1 3 2 3 2 3 1 3 2 2 2 3 3 1 3 3
 1 1 1 3 3 1 3 2 1 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3
 3 3 1 3 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 2 3 1 3 2 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 2 1 3 3 2 3
 3 1 3 2 3 3 1 3 1 3 3 3 3 2 3 1 3 2 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 2 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 3
 3 3 1 2 3 1 1 3 3 3 2 1 3 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 1 3 2 3 3 3 3 1 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 1
 3 1 3]

target is [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0
 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 1 0]

Comment: It may expect X to by a matrix instead of an array.  Try doing a reshape.

Comment: changed `train = np.matrix(train)
target = np.array(target)` but it's still giving the same error.  edit: nevermind, saw that reshape was a function of numpy.

Comment: Try `train = np.array(train)[:, np.newaxis]`. Are we doing your homework?

Comment: That gives me `ValueError: X has 2 features per sample; expecting 1` and for the homework answer: yes and no. My assignment is basically collect a bunch of data from any data set, use a variety of SKlearn functions on it, and see what the output is. The issue here is simply trying to get the input to work which is turning out to be much more difficult than I thought.

Comment: Figured it out. My test case only needed one when I was putting in four variables. Thanks for the help.